# How to stop and reactivate setInterval() with a stack of images using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, setinterval

I have a little problem with the setInterval() function using a JQuery event handler.

I have a stack of images within my HTML. Every 6 sec an image fades out and the next image replaces the previous. This is done by a function imgAutoChange() passed as an argument to setInterval(), like this:

```
var intervalId = setInterval('imgAutoChange()', 6000);
```

I also have two buttons, one with **.prev** class and the other with **.next** class. What I would like to achieve, when I click on the .prev or the .next button, is to reset the ***setInterval('imgAutoChange()', 6000);*** and change the image to the previous if I click on the .prev button or to the next if I click to the .next button so the setInterval restarts every time I click on one of the buttons. (I do the image changing on click by a function called getNxtOrPrevImg() which requires an argument ("p") to get the previous image of the stack and ("n") to get the next image and the function works but I do not understand how to handle the setInterval() )

Actually my js is:

```
var intervalId = setInterval('imgAutoChange()', 6000);

$(function() {
    $('#photcont .act').css("display", "none").fadeIn(2000);
 });        

$(function() {
        $('.leftImgNav').click(function() {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        getNxtOrPrevImg("p");
        var intervalId = setInterval('chgImgs("#photcont")', 6000);
         });

        $('.rightImgNav').click(function() {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            getNxtOrPrevImg("n");
            var intervalId = setInterval('chgImgs("#photcont")', 6000);
        });
 });
```

Plus the functions imgAutoChange() and getNxtOrPrevImg(), I have explained before. 
But it doesn't work. When I click on one of the buttons, the image changes, then another setInterval() starts and I can't stop it anymore with clearInterval...
Is there a smarter way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a scope issue. Within the body of your function, replace `var intervalId` with `intervalId`:

```
$(function() {
    $('.leftImgNav').click(function() {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        getNxtOrPrevImg("p");
        intervalId = setInterval('chgImgs("#photcont")', 6000);
    });

    $('.rightImgNav').click(function() {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        getNxtOrPrevImg("n");
        intervalId = setInterval('chgImgs("#photcont")', 6000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

dont use var before interval id because you are assign another interval in that scope:

```
 var intervalId = setInterval('imgAutoChange()', 6000);

    $(function() {
        $('#photcont .act').css("display", "none").fadeIn(2000);
     });        

    $(function() {
            $('.leftImgNav').click(function() {
            clearInterval(intervalId);

            getNxtOrPrevImg("p");
           intervalId = setInterval('chgImgs("#photcont")', 6000);//dont use var before interval id
             });

            $('.rightImgNav').click(function() {
                clearInterval(intervalId);

                getNxtOrPrevImg("n");
                intervalId = setInterval('chgImgs("#photcont")', 6000);
            });
     });
```